# Showing $F(x) = 1/x \int_0^x f(t) dt$ is increasing

Tags: real-analysis

In proving :

If $f$ is bounded variation on $[0,1]$, then $$F(x) = (1/x) \int_0^x f(t) dt$$ is of bounded variation on $[0,1]$.

I am attempting to prove:  If $f$ is increasing, then $F$ is increasing.

I attempted to bypass the problem in numerous ways but I was unsuccessful.
If I have the claim, I solve the problem.
Can anyone give me a hint?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: On top of my head: if $f$ were continuous, then it would hold $$F'(x)=\frac{f(x)-F(x)}{x}$$ and, since $f$ is increasing and $F(x)$ is the average of $f$ in the interval $[0,x]$, by continuity it follows $F(x)<f(x)$. Perhaps you can recycle this idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We want to show that $x < y \Rightarrow F(x) \leq F(y)$, i.e. $$\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \leq \frac{1}{y}\int_0^y f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$ We note that $$\frac{1}{y}\int_0^y f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{y}\left[\int_0^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t+\int_x^y f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right]$$ Therefore, we can rewrite our inequality as $$\left(\frac{y}{x}-1\right)\int_0^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \leq \int_x^y f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$ We multiply both sides by $\frac{1}{y-x}$ to get $$\frac{\frac{y}{x}-1}{y-x}\int_0^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \leq \frac{1}{y-x}\int_x^y f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$ The left-hand side is the average value of $f(t)$ on $(0, x)$, while the right-hand side is the average value of $f(t)$ on $(x, y)$. The left-hand side is therefore bounded above by $\sup_{t\in (0, x)} f(t)$, while the right-hand side is bounded below by $\inf_{t\in (x, y)} f(t)$. As $f$ is increasing, we therefore have that $$\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \leq \sup_{t\in (0, x)} f(t) \leq \inf_{t\in (x, y)} f(t) \leq \frac{1}{y-x}\int_x^y f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$ so we are done.

Answer (score 4):

Calculate the derivative of $F$: $F'(x) = \frac{\int_0^x (f(x) - f(t)) dt}{x^2}$ almost everywhere. We see that if $f$ is non-decreasing then $F' \geq 0$.

Comment: If $f$ is discontinuous, then $F$ may be nondifferentiable.

Comment: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/16/245a-notes-5-differentiation-theorems/ Theorem 6.

Comment: Elegant solution; +1.

Comment: But i have to admit that there are still some details missing, but i'm certain one can make this argument work. Michael's argument is better if one is not familiar with measure theory.

Comment: I'm not sure how much measure theory is required besides the intuition that a.e. nonnegativity of $F'$ implies that $F$ is increasing. Other than that, considering its brevity, it _is_ a very nice proof.

Comment: @MichaelLee that and taking derivatives a.e. The proof looks very easy, but it's not elementary.

Comment: @MichaelLee: You need measure theory to know that $F$ is absolutely continuous and $F' \ge 0$ a.e. implies non-decreasing $F$.

Comment: This is very nice; thank you.

Comment: But how can you use fundamental theorem of calculus without the condition $f$ is AC?

Answer (score 0):

A simple proof, using a linear substitution: For $0 < x < y$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\boxed{F(x)} &= \frac 1x \int_0^x f(t) \, dt \\
&= \frac 1y \int_0^y f(\frac xy s) \,ds \quad \text{(substitution $t = \frac xy s$)} \\
&\boxed{\le} \frac 1y \int_0^y f(s) \, ds \quad \text{(because $f$ is increasing)}\\
 &= \boxed{F(y)} \, .
\end{align}
$$